# How to Clear values in text box, drop down and checkbox values in asp.net MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Asp.net MVC 4 with C#. I am using a Text box, Drop down and checkbox altogether in a page as a search filter. I am using a button clear to clear the values.while clicking clear button I need to clear the value in textbox, show the "select here" on dropdown(My dropdown values are "Select here", "Value1", "Value2") and uncheck the check box. How to write the script function? My coding is below..

```
     <div class-="container">
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
<label>Id</label>                                                           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Id, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
<label>Role</label>
@Html.DropDownList("SelectRole", new SelectList(@ViewBag._RViewBag, "Key", "Value", Model.Role), new { @class = "form-control" })
 </div>
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
<br />
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Status)&nbsp;&nbsp;<label style="font-size:large">  Status</label></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 btn-top">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-suucess btn-block">Search</a></div>
 <div class="col-md-4 btn-top"><a onclick="Clear()" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Clear</a></div>
```

Can Anyone help me write the Clear Function?

Comment: The simple way is to put the fields inside `form` and add a `button`of type `reset`

Comment: I have been a web developer for years. This is the first I've ever heard of `reset` type. Mind blown. Also, you should create an answer, instead of a comment, because your comment appears to directly answer his question.

Comment: If u didn't heard about reset yet then you are not a good developer :)

Comment: While I greatly appreciate your insult, resetting forms has never been a priority for stuff I do.

Comment: didn't know that neither, good point

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh sir how to use Reset.. Just add inside button also can ah ?

Comment: So it would work like this, if all your text boxes, selects, and check boxes were in a `form` element, then you could have a button in the form like this: `<button type="reset">Reset</button>`, and it `should` reset all values in the form to default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Clear = function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').val(""); //clears text boxes
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false); //unchecks checkboxes
    $('select').val("Select here");
}
```

If I understand correctly, this should do what you need.

Also, as I just learned from the first to comment on your question, you can have a button of type `reset` if all your inputs are in a form.

Comment: sir, my dropdown already have the "Select here" text in it.. so I need to hardcode  those text inside the function or else any other option to display its first index?

Comment: Also, I declared onclick = Clear() ; so that can I write it as a function or declare as a var ? if variable means, where to call that one?

Comment: The way I've always handled setting default options in selects, is to set the value of that option to "" (`value=""`) in the html, and then you can just set it's value in jquery by `$('select').val("")`

Comment: And you can either use `var Cear = function()` or `function Clear()`. For your purposes they'll work the same.

Comment: Sir Your Coding working for both drop down and check box, but for the text box its not working sir...

Comment: Thank you So much sir.. Your Code is just working.. U did a small typo..  $('input[type="text"]').val("");  --In this Line U put Double quotes after the square bracket..that's why it was not worked.. now working.. thank you so much